# Rails encoding HTML inside JSON differently, same version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, heroku

I'm running the same (Rails 4.2.7.1) application in two servers in Heroku and one is working as expected:

```
ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(html: '<p>Hello World</p>')
#=> "{\"html\":\"<p>Hello World</p>\"}
```

The same code running on the second server produces a different result:

```
ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(html: '<p>Hello World</p>')
#=> "{\"html\":\"\\u003cp\\u003eHello World\\u003c/p\\u003e\"}"
```

Both servers have the same Ruby (ruby 2.2.6p396) and from what I've gathered the `ENV['LANG']` plays a role in encoding, but both servers have the same value stored in there: `"en_US.UTF-8"`.

Thanks for your help.

Additional details: Both servers resulting strings are encoded with UTF-8.

```
ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(html: '<p>Hello World</p>').encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

Comment: Is there any difference in how Ruby was compiled? I looked through as much source code from ActiveSupport::JSON.encode to `RUBY_ENCODING_H` constant in the CRuby-sourcecode.. That's as far as I got, if anyone feels like continuing. EDIT: And a bit more searching goes towards compilation with readline support..? However I have no specific answer to the question - Sorry!

Answer (score 6):

It is because of [ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding.escape_html_entities_in_json](http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/ActiveSupport/JSON/Encoding.escape_html_entities_in_json=)

> If true, encode >, <, & as escaped unicode sequences (e.g. > as u003e) as a safety measure

```
ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding.escape_html_entities_in_json = false
encode = ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(html: '<p>Hello World</p>')
#=> "{\"html\":\"<p>Hello World</p>\"}
```

Also the

```
ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding.escape_html_entities_in_json = true
encode = ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(html: '<p>Hello World</p>')
#=> "{\"html\":\"\\u003cp\\u003eHello World\\u003c/p\\u003e\"}"
```

---

Also from the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/98360a96cc1e0bb6ab9eb31f421a36439e66eefc/activesupport/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb#L42-L61), the implementation is quite simple.

```
def to_json(*)
  if Encoding.escape_html_entities_in_json
    super.gsub ESCAPE_REGEX_WITH_HTML_ENTITIES, ESCAPED_CHARS
  else
    super.gsub ESCAPE_REGEX_WITHOUT_HTML_ENTITIES, ESCAPED_CHARS
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, I've since upgraded to Rails 5, where I cannot reproduce the issue. I might deploy a the older version of the app, to a staging server to see what I get with this new info.